# Bash - $PATH and ${PATH}

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, environment-variables

What is the difference between using an environment variable, like PATH, as $PATH or ${PATH}?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no difference in most cases.  The only times it matters is if you want to include trailing text after the expansion.  For example, suppose your `PATH` contained the string `FOO` (not actually a valid path, but this is for an example), and you wanted to form the string `FOOBAR`.  If you did

```
$PATHBAR
```

You would get the expansion of the variable named `PATHBAR`, which is probably not what you wanted.  If you did

```
$PATH BAR
```

You would get a space between `FOO` and `BAR`, also not what you wanted.  The solution is to use braces:

```
${PATH}BAR
```

This gives you `FOOBAR`.

Answer (score 5):

`PATH` is the name of the environment variable, `$PATH` and `${PATH}` are methods of accessing them. The form `${PATH}` is used to allow constructs like `echo ${PATH}b` which would fail using `$PATHb`. Also, `bash` allows lots of parameter replacement stuff which the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) will gladly tell you more about.

Comment: what does the `b` after `${PATH}` mean?

Comment: It'll put a literal "b" after PATH instead of accessing an environment variable named PATHb.  Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no difference, but - take the situation: You have two variables:

```
$FOO = "YA"
$YADA = "bar"
```

then `${$FOODA}` will give you nothing while `${${FOO}DA}` will give you "bar"

Comment: '$FOO = "YA"' is incorrect -- it doesn't do what you think it does. You need to do 'FOO-="YA"'

Comment: No, ${${FOO}DA} will give you a syntax error, but eval '$'{${FOO}DA} will give the contents of $YADA...if you assign to FOO correctly.